# Множественная загрузка изображений

Tags: python, django

Как можно реализовать множественную загрузку изображений в админке без дополнительных инструментов?

В моем понимании необходимо:
1. Добавить виджет к полю загрузки изображений и зарегистрировать его
2. Настроить сохранение всех файлов

1. Я пробовала просто добавить в виджет админки `attr['multipart']=True` и появилась возможность выбора нескольких файлов
2. С сохранением проблема, это уже сложно для меня подскажите где почитать.

   Как я понимаю мне нужна функция сохранения изображений, например:

   ```
    def save_img(images):
        if len(images)==1:
            ...
        else:
            for img in images:
                ...
   ```

В общем если есть у кого какие ссылки по моему вопросу, буду признателен за наводку.

Comment: Нашел решение в статье http://ishalyapin.ru/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%B4-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-django/ но выдает ошибку ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form PhotoAdminForm needs updating . Вот только пока никак не могу понять, что нужно обновить

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашелся в указанной мной статье, а проблема с ошибкой решилась перечислением всех полей в мета классе, итого класс мета:

```
class PhotoAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Photo
    widgets = {'image':MultiFileInput}
    fields="__all__"
```